# How to get the size of a dictionary of tensors

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I have a dictionary of the format below:

```py
dict = {"frame": image, "tag": image_tag}
```

where `image` has the characteristics below:

- type: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>
- dtype: <dtype: 'float32'>
- shape: (1, 512, 512, 3)

`image_tag` is a tensor of type string.

I need to get the size of the dictionary in **byte**. A simple getsizeof() does not work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How did you add ```frame``` key to ```dict```. If you have read it using ```f = open("img.jpg","r")``` or something like that, you can use ```os``` module to get the size. ```n = os.stat("img.jpg")``` and then ```n.st_size``` will give file size in bytes.

Comment: I used this function: image = tensorflow.io.read_file("img.jpg")

Comment: If the data in ```frame``` key is still in binary form, you can use this, ```len(bytearray(dict['frame']))```. It will print the length of byte array. Which is the size of the image in bytes.